# How to find a confidence level given the z value

Tags: r, python, statistics

I have a task from which I would like to find the confidence level given the z value. I have a sample population. From that population, given its distribution, I would like to find the confidence level of a given value of that population. In other words, given a a value of the population, I would like to know if it is within 95% (confidence level) of the whole population or 68% or 50% and so on. Usually, we can find the z value and confidence interval and given confidence level as explained here [How to find the confidence Interval](http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Confidence-Interval). But I would like to find the confidence level given the z value (which in this case is a given value from the population).

How can I tackle this? If possible it should be in python or in R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, for a 95% confidence interval, you want to know how many standard deviations away from the mean your point estimate is (the "z-score").  To get that, you take off the 5% "tails".  Working in percentile form you have 100-95 which yields a value of 5, or 0.05 in decimal form.

Divide that in half to get 0.025 and then, in R, use the qnorm function to get the z-star ("critical value").  Since you only care about one "side" of the curve (the values on either side are mirror images of each other) and you want a positive number, pass the argument lower.tail=FALSE.

So, in the end, it would look like this:

```
qnorm(.025,lower.tail=FALSE)
```

yielding a value of 1.959964

You then plug that value into the equation for the margin of error to finish things up.

If you want to go the other direction, from a "critical value" to a probability, use the pnorm function.  Something like:

```
pnorm(1.959964,lower.tail=FALSE)
```

which will give you back 0.025

Comment: I could have worded that better, but the net-net is "use qnorm/pnorm".

Answer (score 1):

To convert between z-scores and confidence values with python, use the `cdf` and `ppf` functions in [scipy.stats.norm](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html).

There is a nice example of how to use them in the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864847/probability-to-z-score-and-vice-versa-in-python).